# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Session'

Tags: python, flask

When I run my python script `file.py`, I get an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Session'`.

The imports on my script:

```
import os
import sys
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import random
import time
import requests
from requests import Request, Session
from flask_session import Session
from flask_session.__init__ import Session
import Session

from setup_inception import ImageNet, InceptionModel
```

Comment: Please share the code

Comment: Where are you importing Session from?

Comment: Hi Masha, welcome to SO. Besides the code, can you identify the python version you are using? Are using a virtualenv?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is a Flask issue, and has nothing to do with `deep-learning` or `tensorflow` (tags edited). Also, please post the full error trace (not clear where exactly the error pops up, and you are trying to import Session several times).

Comment: Python 3.8.3 (default, Jul  2 2020, 16:21:59) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 7.19.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

runfile('/home/mahsa/Desktop/..../test_all_MSP.py', wdir='/home/mahsa/Desktop/...')
2020-12-21 14:08:18.014973: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/mahsa/Desktop/..../test_all_MSP.py", line 20, in <module>
    import Session

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Session'

Comment: Hi thanks a lot! after run the *.py file, I come that error

Comment: My python version is 3.8

Comment: and I use spyder version 4.2.0

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `from flask_session import Session`

Instead use `from flask_session.__init__ import Session`

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for the late answer, I have solved the problem with command:

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
```

instead of

```
 import tensorflow as tf
```

because I 'm using `tensorflow 2.4`